# How do I add a sprite to an object layer?

Tags: phaser, tiled

I am using **Tiled** to create a map which I am then using for a game written in **Phaser**.

I cannot figure out how to add a Sprite into the **Object layer** using the Tiled editor.   I am having to do it with code but that's not ideal as I want to see the sprites in their positions on the map when I edit it.

I know this is very simple but I cannot see how to add/see sprites in Tiled.  Is Tiled not able to do this or not designed to do this?

Comment: I don't actually think its possible, you can add in objects and adjust the size of them to "pretend" they are sprites.. But as to actually adding an image to that object, I believe that functionality isn't available.

Comment: Yeah I see what you mean, you can add tiles to the object layer but not sprites.  Tiles, when added to the object layer, are sprites.  I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all your sprite image needs to be part of a tileset. If your sprites use individual images, you should use Tiled >= 0.10 so that you can set up a tileset as a "Collection of Images" which you then add images to individually with the + button below the tileset view.

Then create an Object Layer, select the sprite you want to insert in the tileset view and select the "Insert Tile" tool from the tool bar. Then click on the map to add each sprite object. You can hold your mouse button while placing to position them more easily, or select and move them later with the Object Selection tool.

Comment: Yep, got it, thanks.  I think I was confused by the fact I am using a sprite from a tilesheet.  (Using tiles as sprites).  Up until now I've been adding them to the tile layer instead and then 'converting' them into sprites using code.  But this will be much better, ie. adding the sprites directly on Tiled.  So thanks.